# What happened to the Protect/Unprotect button?

Tags: discussion, protection

I have noticed that the "Protect/Unprotect" button no longer exists where I was used to see it. Has this functionality been eliminated (site-wide or network-wide)?

Comment: It's working, I just tried it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1164977/timeline)

Comment: @ArcticChar: Indeed, I can see it for that question, too. Could you please take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463785/) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1835948/) and tell me if you see the "Protect/Unprotect" button? Thank you.

Comment: That's because of the criteria that Asaf mentioned below. I just downvoted one of the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835948/radius-of-convergence-for-polynomial), so that (poor) answer-er now has <10 reps, and the protect bottom shows up when I refresh.

Comment: @ArcticChar: Thank you, that explains it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you're not giving an example, I can only assume that the following information is relevant:

> Which questions can be protected?
> Any question at least a day old can be protected and unprotected by users that have the privilege, provided the question has received at least one answer from a user with less than 10 reputation. Diamond Moderators can protect and unprotect a question at any time.
>
> Some questions may be protected automatically by our system in specific situations, often due to having many deleted or negatively-scoring answers in a short period of time.

(Taken from https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)

So that in effect, you're simply looking at "too new of questions". I can confirm that the option to protect appears in the moderator menu, so the feature as a whole, has not been removed from the network.

Comment: Right, this was it: *"[...] provided the question has received at least one answer from a user with less than 10 reputation"*.